# How to get access token after the existing access token is expired in Azure application

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-ad-msal

I am using an iframe inside my web application which is registered in Azure and IdP is MS Azure. Now using MSAL I can get the access_token and id_token by using acquireTokenSilent method. But when the access_token expires, how do I refresh it from the iframe scope(where MSAL is not available). Since this is a implicit grant I do not hold refresh token.

Is it possible to get the new access_token using any of the below

1. client_id
2. client_secret
3. Old access token or id_token and raw_id_token

I have tried the 'token' and 'authorise' endpoints from login.microsoftonline.com, but those could not provide me the new access_token.

Comment: You can use **iFrame** to send silent requests with user cookies, where the session will validate the request and issue a new access token. As mentioned in the document, you can use the **prompt=none** option to accomplish this.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#refreshing-tokens

Comment: Do you have to use  Implicit flow or is it your choice?

Comment: @CarlZhao Thanks! And I have to use implicit grant type only, there is no choice.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **iFrame** to send [silent requests](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OpenID-Connect/Silent-Refresh-Refreshing-Access-Tokens-when-using-the-Implicit-Flow) with user cookies, where the session will validate the request and issue a new access token. As mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#refreshing-tokens), you can use the **prompt=none** option to accomplish this.

By the way, for security considerations, it is recommended that you use [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-javascript-auth-code), which will return a **refresh token** to you when you request a token.

Comment: I have integrated the autorize endpoint for fecthing the access token in background, but I get the below error 

login_required&error_description=AADSTS50058%3a+A+silent+sign-in+request+was+sent+but+no+user+is+signed+in.+The+cookies+used+to+represent+the+user%27s+session+were+not+sent+in+the+request+to+Azure+AD